# Subgroups. Prove Theorem: If $G$ is a group, then $G\leq G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Theorem: If $G$ is a group, prove $G\leq G$.

This proof seems straight forward, but I am having a hard time forming a coherent proof.

Ideas: We assume $G$ is a group. Then we prove any element in $G$ satisfies the following properties of a group. Let $x\in G$. Show that $x$ satisfies the binary operation and has an identity element in $G$?

I am brand new to proofs.

Comment: $G$ is a group. $G$ is a subset of $G$. That's pretty much all there is.

Comment: Lol, thank you.

Comment: Here it seems important that you find out why you had a hard time. So the claim is: if $G$ is a group, then $G$ is a subgroup of itself. Now can you formulate the axioms (or criteria) for being a subgroup? Then the next step is to verify them just by using the axioms from the assumption.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, I agree. I wrote down the intuitive answer, but just wanted more so to confirm I wasn't being "lazy." Lack of sleep leads to non-thinking or overthinking. Thank you for your response.

Comment: If you want I can write down a "formal standard solution". Of course, you know it already.

Comment: That would be helpful. I am always open to any and all approaches. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showing $G \leq G$ is as trivial as showing that $G$ is a group, when you already know that $G$ is a group.

> For a set $H \subseteq G$ to be a **subgroup** of $G$ it must satisfy the
>   following criteria:
>
> $\bullet \space$ **Closure:** $\forall h_1,h_2 \in H: \space$ $h_1
>  \cdot h_2 \in H$, where $\cdot$ is $G$'s binary operation.
>
> $\bullet \space$ **Identity:** $\space \exists e \in H$
>
> $\bullet \space$ **Inverses:**$\space \forall h\in H, \exists h^{-1}
>  \in H$ s.t. $h \cdot h^{-1}=e.$

In your case, when $H=G \subseteq G$, all criteria are satisfied *by definition*:

$\bullet \space$**Closure:** $\forall g_1,g_2 \in G$: $\space g_1 \cdot g_2 \in G$, since $G$ is a group.

$\bullet \space$ **Identinty:** $e \in G$, since $G$ is a group.

$\bullet \space$ **Inverses:** $\forall g \in G, \exists g^{-1}$ s.t. $g \cdot g^{-1}=e$, since $G$ is a group.

To summarize, for a group to be a subgroup of itself, the only necessary and sufficient condition is to be a group. That's why the whole group is called the **trivial subgroup** of itself.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation and easy to follow steps.

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for supporting my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggestion for a "standard solution", discussed in the comments.

*Claim:* Let $G$ be a group. Then $G$ is a subgroup of $G$.

*Proof*: We use the following result, which is usually available in the lecture right after the definition of a subgroup: a non-empty subset $S\subseteq G$ is a subgroup, if and only if $xy\in S$ for all $x,y\in S$ and $x^{-1}\in S$ for all $x\in S$. Both conditions are satisfied for $S=G$ by the very definition of a group, i.e., because $G$ is a group.